# Does Jboss EAP6.4 support "JSONObject" Mapping of jersey web service?

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to run  the jersey web services in the JBOSS EAP6.4 but the **JSONObject** mapping is not working . However , the same war file is working in tomcat & weblogic server for the request/repsonse flow .

REST method declaration:

```
@POST
@Path("/getUser")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User test(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
                 @Context HttpServletResponse response,
                 JSONObject jsonObject) {...}
```

Thanks

Comment: JSONObject is not something that is support. Just accept a String parameter, and construct the JSONObject yourself with that string

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet . We are currently converting String to JSONbject in the code and wanted to confirm the JSONObject mapping will be supported in JBOSS EAP or not.

Comment: Not exactly sure what mapping you are talking about?

Comment: The POJOMappingFeature should work, but you need to 1) make sure you have the jersey-json dependency, and 2) You need to use POJOs. It doesn't work with JSONObject

Comment: Thanks . I was referring to the JSONObject Mapping and let me correct the Question title as well .

Answer (score 1):

According to the JavaEE 6 specification, JBoss EAP 6 is required to provide a JAX-RS implementation, which is done via RESTEasy. It is recommended not to package your own JAX-RS implementation. However, if you must use and package a different JAX-RS implementation (like Jersey), it will be considered by Red Hat as part of your own application.